# How to load a ListView using SQLite in Titanium?

Tags: sqlite, listview, backbone.js, titanium

I'm actually using the framework Alloy. I have tried in my model .js this:

```
var myBooks = Alloy.Collections.books;

Var getData = myBooks.fetch();
```

However, for setting up the ListView it's required get Array type and to be honest I only know that with the getData variable I got an object of type Backbone.Object and I not figure out how to map it.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, It is not necessary to parse the value to an array and call the line:

```
$.elementsOnList.section[0].setItems(books);
```

Intead of you can simply:

```
//Get a reference to our collection:
Alloy.Collections.books.fetch();
```

And in the view .js make use of the properties that offer Titanium through its framework Alloy:

```
<Alloy>
  <Collection src="books" />
    <Window>
    <ListView defaultItemTemplate="by_name">
      <Templates>
        <ItemTemplate name="by_name">
          <View>
            <Label bindId="title"/>
          </View>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </Templates>
      <ListSection dataCollection="books">
        <ListItem title:text="{title}" />
      </ListSection>
    </ListView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

And with that few lines of code my list is loading data from the database.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't written for Alloy, but it's plug-and-play code.

```
// Create main window
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:"#bbb",
    navBarHidden : true,
    orientationModes : [Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT]
});

// Install the database
var db = Ti.Database.install("myDB.sqlite", "myDB");
db.close();

// Create the empty array
var myBooks = [];

// Set data in the app
function setData(){
    var db = Ti.Database.open("myDB");
    // Select the "books" table in the database
    var rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books");
    while (rows.isValidRow()) {
    // Add each "title" under the books table to the array
    myBooks.push(rows.fieldByName("title"));
    rows.next();
    }
    rows.close();
    db.close();
    // Print the array
    Ti.API.info(myBooks);
}

// call the function
setData();

win.open();
```

I just made a simple database in sqlite with one table "books", and then "titles" under books. Within "books" I added three values, "Book One", "Book Two" and "Book Three".

From here you should be able to use the myBooks array to add to your ListView in Alloy.

Comment: Thank you Peach Pellen, do you have any idea of how can I change the default bar color of a menu? <Menu id="menu" >
       <!-- Cannot specify node text.  Use attributes only. -->
        <MenuItem 
           title="Add book"
           onClick="addBook"
           showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM" />
   </Menu>... I tried from .tss but It never changes

Comment: I suspect where you changed it was wrong, have you looked at this; https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/blob/master/samples/todo/styles/row.tss ? Try changing another element in tss and see if it makes a difference. If not, compare your setup to that linked app.